# Branch removendo arquivos da branch master

Tags: git

Minha duvida é a seguinte: Estou em um branch tentando dar merge da minha branch master. Porém o git está ignorando alguns arquivos quando o merge é dado.

Como fazer para forçar colocar tudo?

Answer (score 0):

Bem, eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
git checkout branch_que_quero_dar_o_merge

git checkout branch_em_que_quero_arquivos -- pasta/ou/arquivos
```

Assim, se o `merge` está deletando algum arquivo, você pode simplesmente pegá-los novamente do outro branch através do checkout com o outro branch especificado.